# Monthly increment starting in a month number in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a calculate column with DAX, where from the starting month of a calendar, start a sequence for each month. It would be something like this:

[image]

I am totally lost here, I dont know if someone can please help me.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
New Column :=
VAR FirstYear =
    YEAR ( MIN ( Table1[DATE] ) )
VAR ThisYear =
    YEAR ( Table1[DATE] )
VAR ThisMonth =
    MONTH ( Table1[DATE] )
RETURN
    ThisMonth + ( ThisYear - FirstYear ) * 12
```

amending the table name as required.

Answer (score 1):

One of the opiton is to add column in DAX like this (but @Jos Woolley solution should be faster):

```
Column = 
var _currYearMonth = FORMAT([Date],"yyyyMM")
var _list = filter(summarize(SELECTCOLUMNS(CAL,"yearMonth", FORMAT([Date],"yyyyMM")),[yearMonth]), [yearMonth] <= _currYearMonth)
return
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(_list))
```